# Modify value of a text-multi input of a content fragment in content fragment editor by JavaScript

Tags: aem

I have a content fragment model with a field (call it document type) of resource type cq/gui/components/coral/common/form/tagfield and a field (call it resume) of resource type dam/cfm/admin/components/authoring/contenteditor/multieditor and I want to set a default text for the resume field based on the document type selected.

The resume field is like that:

```
<input type="hidden" data-cfm-multieditor-inputfield="true" class="coral-Form-field" data-cfminput="true" data-type="string" data-element="resume" data-type-multi="false" data-content-type="text/html" name="resume" value="This is the value to change" data-content-upload-path="/content/dam/es/foobarproject/documents/2023/01/foobar-content-fragment.cfm.upload.json" data-title="Upload Content">
```

I try by doing this:

```
$(document).on('foundation-contentloaded', function (e) {

    const documentTypeField = document.getElementsByName('typeEms')[0]
    const resumeField = document.getElementsByName('resume')[0]
    var resumeP = resumeField.find('p')

    documentTypeField.addEventListener('change', () => {

        if (documentTypeField.value === 'foobarproject:documents/foo-type-document') {
            resumeField.setAttribute("value", 'TEST')
            resumeP.setAttribute("value", 'TEST')
        }
    })
})
```

The problem is: if I try to modify the value of the resume field by:
resumeField.setAttribute("value", 'TEST')
when I print the resume field by console.log('Resume:', resumeField) it prints the field with 'TEST' as value but the field in the editor has not changed its value.
If I try to change the < p > element of the resume field (which also has the value of resume field) then I get the following error in the console:

```
Could not create new version of the fragment. foobar-content-fragment
    level http://localhost:4502/editor.html/content/dam/es/foobarproject/documents/2023/01/foobar-content-fragment
    fail http://localhost:4502/libs/dam/cfm/admin/clientlibs/v2/adminpage.12d321b51ba9cced9850d6d4801c803f.js line 266 > srcScript:325
    executeHandlers http://localhost:4502/libs/dam/cfm/admin/clientlibs/v2/adminpage.12d321b51ba9cced9850d6d4801c803f.js line 266 > srcScript:691
    handleFail http://localhost:4502/libs/dam/cfm/admin/clientlibs/v2/adminpage.12d321b51ba9cced9850d6d4801c803f.js line 266 > srcScript:666
    jqXHR http://localhost:4502/libs/dam/cfm/admin/clientlibs/v2/adminpage.12d321b51ba9cced9850d6d4801c803f.js line 266 > srcScript:782
    jQuery 6
    executeUnblockedRequests http://localhost:4502/libs/dam/cfm/admin/clientlibs/v2/adminpage.12d321b51ba9cced9850d6d4801c803f.js line 266 > srcScript:775
    startQueue http://localhost:4502/libs/dam/cfm/admin/clientlibs/v2/adminpage.12d321b51ba9cced9850d6d4801c803f.js line 266 > srcScript:882
    schedule http://localhost:4502/libs/dam/cfm/admin/clientlibs/v2/adminpage.12d321b51ba9cced9850d6d4801c803f.js line 266 > srcScript:873
    start http://localhost:4502/libs/dam/cfm/admin/clientlibs/v2/adminpage.12d321b51ba9cced9850d6d4801c803f.js line 266 > srcScript:295
    start http://localhost:4502/libs/dam/cfm/admin/clientlibs/v2/adminpage.12d321b51ba9cced9850d6d4801c803f.js line 266 > srcScript:1061
    notifyModification http://localhost:4502/libs/dam/cfm/admin/clientlibs/v2/adminpage.12d321b51ba9cced9850d6d4801c803f.js line 266 > srcScript:1151
    <anonymous> http://localhost:4502/libs/dam/cfm/admin/clientlibs/v2/adminpage.12d321b51ba9cced9850d6d4801c803f.js line 266 > srcScript:1034
    jQuery 7
    <anonymous> http://localhost:4502/libs/dam/cfm/admin/clientlibs/v2/adminpage.12d321b51ba9cced9850d6d4801c803f.js line 266 > srcScript:1028
    jQuery 7
    _triggerChangeEvent http://localhost:4502/etc.clientlibs/granite/ui/components/coral/foundation/clientlibs/foundation.5503c8b230b7dc6f54303586f6233cbc.js:3542
    f http://localhost:4502/etc.clientlibs/granite/ui/components/coral/foundation/clientlibs/foundation.5503c8b230b7dc6f54303586f6233cbc.js:3524
    jQuery 12
    _onValueChangeByUser http://localhost:4502/etc.clientlibs/granite/ui/components/coral/foundation/clientlibs/foundation.5503c8b230b7dc6f54303586f6233cbc.js:3518
    _setSelections http://localhost:4502/etc.clientlibs/granite/ui/components/coral/foundation/clientlibs/foundation.5503c8b230b7dc6f54303586f6233cbc.js:3624
    _getValueAPI http://localhost:4502/etc.clientlibs/granite/ui/components/coral/foundation/clientlibs/foundation.5503c8b230b7dc6f54303586f6233cbc.js:3578
    _setSelections http://localhost:4502/etc.clientlibs/granite/ui/components/coral/foundation/clientlibs/foundation.5503c8b230b7dc6f54303586f6233cbc.js:3600
    _appendValue http://localhost:4502/etc.clientlibs/granite/ui/components/coral/foundation/clientlibs/foundation.5503c8b230b7dc6f54303586f6233cbc.js:3657
    jQuery 8
    _appendValue http://localhost:4502/etc.clientlibs/granite/ui/components/coral/foundation/clientlibs/foundation.5503c8b230b7dc6f54303586f6233cbc.js:3652
    _getSuggestionAPI http://localhost:4502/etc.clientlibs/granite/ui/components/coral/foundation/clientlibs/foundation.5503c8b230b7dc6f54303586f6233cbc.js:3560
    _appendValue http://localhost:4502/etc.clientlibs/granite/ui/components/coral/foundation/clientlibs/foundation.5503c8b230b7dc6f54303586f6233cbc.js:3651
    _onUserInput http://localhost:4502/etc.clientlibs/granite/ui/components/coral/foundation/clientlibs/foundation.5503c8b230b7dc6f54303586f6233cbc.js:3481
    (Asíncrono: setTimeout handler)
    createdCallback http://localhost:4502/etc.clientlibs/granite/ui/components/coral/foundation/clientlibs/foundation.5503c8b230b7dc6f54303586f6233cbc.js:3011
    (Asíncrono: EventListener.handleEvent)
    createdCallback http://localhost:4502/etc.clientlibs/granite/ui/components/coral/foundation/clientlibs/foundation.5503c8b230b7dc6f54303586f6233cbc.js:3009
    i http://localhost:4502/etc.clientlibs/clientlibs/granite/coralui3.7caefb86dc764d3d3fcbd8ff1d8c65b4.js:4207
    n http://localhost:4502/etc.clientlibs/clientlibs/granite/coralui3.7caefb86dc764d3d3fcbd8ff1d8c65b4.js:4207
    t http://localhost:4502/etc.clientlibs/clientlibs/granite/coralui3.7caefb86dc764d3d3fcbd8ff1d8c65b4.js:4207
    n http://localhost:4502/etc.clientlibs/clientlibs/granite/coralui3.7caefb86dc764d3d3fcbd8ff1d8c65b4.js:4207
    o http://localhost:4502/etc.clientlibs/clientlibs/granite/coralui3.7caefb86dc764d3d3fcbd8ff1d8c65b4.js:4207
    t http://localhost:4502/etc.clientlibs/clientlibs/granite/coralui3.7caefb86dc764d3d3fcbd8ff1d8c65b4.js:4207
    n http://localhost:4502/etc.clientlibs/clientlibs/granite/coralui3.7caefb86dc764d3d3fcbd8ff1d8c65b4.js:4207
    n http://localhost:4502/etc.clientlibs/clientlibs/granite/coralui3.7caefb86dc764d3d3fcbd8ff1d8c65b4.js:4207
    n http://localhost:4502/etc.clientlibs/clientlibs/granite/coralui3.7caefb86dc764d3d3fcbd8ff1d8c65b4.js:4207
    n http://localhost:4502/etc.clientlibs/clientlibs/granite/coralui3.7caefb86dc764d3d3fcbd8ff1d8c65b4.js:4207
    n http://localhost:4502/etc.clientlibs/clientlibs/granite/coralui3.7caefb86dc764d3d3fcbd8ff1d8c65b4.js:4207
    n http://localhost:4502/etc.clientlibs/clientlibs/granite/coralui3.7caefb86dc764d3d3fcbd8ff1d8c65b4.js:4207
    n http://localhost:4502/etc.clientlibs/clientlibs/granite/coralui3.7caefb86dc764d3d3fcbd8ff1d8c65b4.js:4207
    n http://localhost:4502/etc.clientlibs/clientlibs/granite/coralui3.7caefb86dc764d3d3fcbd8ff1d8c65b4.js:4207
    n http://localhost:4502/etc.clientlibs/clientlibs/granite/coralui3.7caefb86dc764d3d3fcbd8ff1d8c65b4.js:4207
    n http://localhost:4502/etc.clientlibs/clientlibs/granite/coralui3.7caefb86dc764d3d3fcbd8ff1d8c65b4.js:4207
    n http://localhost:4502/etc.clientlibs/clientlibs/granite/coralui3.7caefb86dc764d3d3fcbd8ff1d8c65b4.js:4207
    n http://localhost:4502/etc.clientlibs/clientlibs/granite/coralui3.7caefb86dc764d3d3fcbd8ff1d8c65b4.js:4207
    t http://localhost:4502/etc.clientlibs/clientlibs/granite/coralui3.7caefb86dc764d3d3fcbd8ff1d8c65b4.js:4207
    o http://localhost:4502/etc.clientlibs/clientlibs/granite/coralui3.7caefb86dc764d3d3fcbd8ff1d8c65b4.js:4207
    t http://localhost:4502/etc.clientlibs/clientlibs/granite/coralui3.7caefb86dc764d3d3fcbd8ff1d8c65b4.js:4207
    v http://localhost:4502/etc.clientlibs/clientlibs/granite/coralui3.7caefb86dc764d3d3fcbd8ff1d8c65b4.js:4207
    i http://localhost:4502/etc.clientlibs/clientlibs/granite/coralui3.7caefb86dc764d3d3fcbd8ff1d8c65b4.js:4207
    r http://localhost:4502/etc.clientlibs/clientlibs/granite/coralui3.7caefb86dc764d3d3fcbd8ff1d8c65b4.js:4207
    h http://localhost:4502/etc.clientlibs/clientlibs/granite/coralui3.7caefb86dc764d3d3fcbd8ff1d8c65b4.js:4207
    t http://localhost:4502/etc.clientlibs/clientlibs/granite/coralui3.7caefb86dc764d3d3fcbd8ff1d8c65b4.js:4207
    (Asíncrono: EventListener.handleEvent)
    <anonymous> http://localhost:4502/etc.clientlibs/clientlibs/granite/coralui3.7caefb86dc764d3d3fcbd8ff1d8c65b4.js:4207
    <anonymous> http://localhost:4502/etc.clientlibs/clientlibs/granite/coralui3.7caefb86dc764d3d3fcbd8ff1d8c65b4.js:4207
```

How can I change the value of the resume field by JavaScript in the content fragment editor?